# Text display issues - certain applications only show a and _

Tags: debian, fonts, display

I'm using a Debian 8 with testing repositories and i3wm. Quite a while ago some applications (vlc, ownCloud client, qbittorrent, teamspeak3) started to only display 'a's and underscores as dialog and menu text. <strike>Seems like all this application are using wxWidget.</strike>
I've already tried unloading the intel video driver as suggested in some archlinux forum, but without success.

[image: VLC with display issue]

My problem is, that I'm completely lost with this. I don't have any starting point or idea what can causes this.

Comment: Neither qbittorrent nor vlc (don't know about the others) use wxwidgets.

Comment: Maybe it's a wrong/missing font or locale.  Test:  find a widget that allows copying, and copy a block of "a_" text, then paste it to a terminal or some other unaffected program.  Check if it  outputs "a_", or garbage text, or regular text.

Comment: It doesn't *look* like a font problem, but one way to see would be by looking at `open` calls via `strace`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I've created an strace for vlc and looked at the open calls, but haven't found anything suspicious: https://gist.github.com/FreakyBytes/103e6a773e01147684e8a5ee3c10b9f6
Also when copy/pasted the text looks alright